# Codeiginter domain and subdmain issue for the same database and code

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm creating a  web app in codeigniter and i'm trying to determine how to route to a specific controller based on whether a subdomain exists or not.

Currently I have it so if you put a url of subdomain.example.com, my default controller checks whether the subdomain in the url exists in the database, and if it does not, it displays the error page.

This works great for urls where a user enters a subdomain, but now if the user enters a url without a subdomain such as example.com, I want a different controller to be used.

What is the best way to achieve this? I was thinking of doing the following, but it doesn't seem best to have a redirect occuring every time someone goes to example.com.

```
if (  strstr  ($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'some-subdomain.mydomain.com'))
{
    $route['uristring'] = "Dashboard";
}
else
{
    $route['default_controller'] = 'admin';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for reading my question I got the answer

```
 $subdomain_arr = explode('.', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 2); //creates the various parts
        $subdomain_name = $subdomain_arr[0];
    //echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];//output www.example.com;

if ($subdomain_name == 'example') {
 $route['default_controller'] = "Admin";
}else{
$route['default_controller'] = 'Dashboard';
}
```